# How do i Click Jquery .Load Event to Change Active Tab

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am trying to set up a way so i can have a specific tab load when i click on certain things. This is the code that is working perfectly, but it is NOT loading a specific tab, it loads into the tab, but does not make it "active"

How would i choose to make "$tabs-1" active ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#leftlist ').click(function() { 
var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
$('#tabs-1').load(url);
return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: What kind of tabs are you using? what does it mean to make it "active"? do you want to add the class active to the "tabs-1" div?

Comment: they are jquery UI tabs

Comment: What i mean is make it focused, so i have 3 tabs, and when i click on the link i want it to open the first tab, and load that content..

Comment: yes tabs-1 is static, so are tabs-2 and tabs-3